# Pokemon radar ring slow to reveal Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-go

When hunting Pokémon with the Fam, my radar always seems to be the last to have the same Pokémon show up (usually to the rear of the radar ring).  Sometimes they never show up in my game at all.  It should have nothing to do with internet strength or ISP because I'm providing the hotspot and we all have the same cell phone service.  Is there a trick to strengthen the radar ring signal?  I've also deleted and reloaded the Pokémon Go App 3 times.

Comment: If I had to guess what is going on, your smartphone is updating the radar ring slower than other cellphones, quite possibly because your phone is acting as the hotspot, which siphons some of your device's CPU and memory. As an experiment, have someone else run the hotspot on their phone for a while and see if they take the performance hit when they do. Another possibility is that your phone is older (and thus slower) than the other phones, or your phone is running background processes which slow it down.

Comment: A little more information...I'm not always providing a hotspot and the same thing happens.  About 30% of the time nothing shows up for me (Galaxy S6), but it does for my wife (iPhone 6) and son (LG3).  They can even catch while we're driving up to ~30 mph.  We're at Levels 26, 27 and 25, respectively.  I'll check background programs, but this is a work phone where I loaded Pokémon Go for my 8 year old so nothing more than email in the background.